# Firebase Database Reference To Retrieve Children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that consists of the following:

1. Event
2. Creators ID (Firebaseauth id)
3. Event name
4. Event attributes like name location date time...

Here's a sample of my database:

[image: Screenshot of database]

What I want is to retrieve the attributes of every event in the database regardless of the UID but I cant get rid of the UID for many other reasons.

Im using the following code to retrieve:

```
ref = database.getReference("Event/");
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Event event = new Event();
                event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                events.add(event);
                myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Where Event is a custom class containing the attributes, getters/setters and constructor of the event.
Ref is the database reference.
But the event object returned is empty.

I am using android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have one level to reach a single Event:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
             for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Event event = new Event();
                event = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                events.add(event);
                myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
          }
            }
```

Also make sure that your Event class have public getters and setters so it can be deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are retrive in the wrong way, try this:

```
String EVENT_ID = "YOUR EVENT ID HERE"
ref = database.getReference("Event")
      .child(EVENT_ID)
      .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Event event = new Event();
                event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                events.add(event);
                myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

**OBS:** put the event id inside **EVENT_ID**. It will work.